# How to use Sscan with interface

Tags: string, go, interface

I'm using to `fmt.Sscan` convert a string to any type, here is what I'm doing:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func test() interface{} {
    return 0
}

func main() {
    a := test() // this could be any type
    v := "10" // this could be anything

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(a), reflect.TypeOf(&a))

    _, err := fmt.Sscan(v, &a)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

This code is failing because `Sscan` doesn't accept interfaces as the second value: `can't scan type: *interface {}`. [demo](https://play.golang.org/p/erWYMahIunf)

What I find most weird is that the first print prints: `int *interface {}`, is it a int or an interface?

How can I assert `a` to the right type (it could be any primitive)? Is there a solution that doesn't include a giant switch statement?

Thank you.

Comment: You almost never want a pointer to an interface. You most likely want an `interface{}` typed value with an underlying pointer type e.g. `*int`.

Comment: @ThunderCat the problem is: `convert a string to any type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to convert a string to a value of any type supported by the `fmt` package:

```
// convert converts s to the type of argument t and returns a value of that type.
func convert(s string, t interface{}) (interface{}, error) {

    // Create pointer to value of the target type
    v := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(t))

    // Scan to the value by passing the pointer SScan 
    _, err := fmt.Sscan(s, v.Interface())

    // Dereference the pointer and return the value.
    return v.Elem().Interface(), err
}
```

Call it like this:

```
a := test()
a, err := convert("10", a)
fmt.Println(a, err)
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UXD-jEWKOC6)

Comment: what about this case: https://play.golang.org/p/MHfeDrNembl ? Let's say that test can return any valid primitive type.

Comment: + I only know it in run time, so I can't really use type assertion.